# Calculate Operation Speed on Datatable Vs GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I have to get total and do sum calculation with reference of that, then which is speedy for fetch particular row or cell from (Datatable/Gridview).

I have same data in both Datatable (fetch from View state each time) and Gridview.

Comment: in most cases: faster without UI.

Comment: Reading something from properties of a UI control is local call to RAM it's certainly faster and safer from a database call which requires a DB connection and running a query. It depends on your particular case though

Comment: @Emad DataTable I am loading DataTable from ViewState and for that i do not call DB Connection each Time.

Comment: That's true. I said it depends on how you do it. If I were you and I was really looking for performance I would sacrifice RAM and load whole data into RAM like in a `List<T>` then bind both UI and my search algorithm on it. Again it depends on particular case.